# laplace transform probability distribution not concentrated on 0

Tags: probability-theory, laplace-transform

This seems intuitively obvious but how to prove that $\hat{\mu} < 1,$ when $\theta >0$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure not concentrated at $0,$ where $\hat{\mu}$ is defined as below 
$$\hat{\mu}(\theta) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\theta x}d\mu(x)$$

Comment: By "$\mu$ not concentrated at $0$" do you mean $\mu(\{0\})<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu(\{0\})<1$, then as $e^{-\theta x}<1$ for $\theta,x>0$ we have 
\begin{align}
\hat\mu(\theta) &= \mu(\{0\}) + \int_{(0,\infty)} e^{-\theta x}\ \mathsf d\mu(x)\\ 
&< \mu(\{0\}) + \int_{(0,\infty)}\ \mathsf d\mu(x)\\
&=\mu(\{0\}) + \mu((0,\infty))\\
&=\mu([0,\infty))\\
&\leqslant 1.
\end{align}